# i am facing this error (1054, "Unknown column 'id' in 'erp_app_invoice'")

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

[image]

hello i am newbie in this field, at the beginning everything's worked fine however i faced this error (1054, "Unknown column 'id' in 'erp_app_invoice'") after making some changes in my models.py. notice that i dont have id in my models.py as it should be generated automatically as far as i know

i tried adding id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) but it didn't work due to the fact that i cant have 2 AutoFields, also tried to make it as CharField but that didn't work also.

```
class Invoice(models.Model):

owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, editable=False)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
product1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
product1_qty = models.CharField(max_length=3)
product1_price = models.CharField(max_length=50)
product1_total = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
product2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
product2_qty = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True)
product2_price = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
product2_total = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
product3 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
product3_qty = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True)
product3_price = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
product3_total = models.CharField(max_length=50)
shipping_fees = models.CharField(max_length=50)
sub_total = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
discount = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
total_order = models.CharField(max_length=50)

def __str__(self):
    return(f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name} | {self.phone}")
```

---

--> .HTML
{% extends "base.html" %}

```
{% block content%}

<h1>My Invoices</h1>
<br/><br/>

<a type="button" href="{% url 'services' %}" class="btn btn-secondary">Back</a>
<a type="button" href="{% url 'add_invoice' %}" class="btn btn-success">Add Invoice</a>
<br/><br/>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead class="table-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Phone</th>
            <th scope="col">Address</th>
            <th scope="col">Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <body>
{% if invoices %}
    {% for invoice in invoices %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{% url 'invoice' invoice.id %}">{{ invoice.id }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ invoice.created_at }}</td>
            <td>{{ invoice.first_name }} {{ invoice.last_name }}</td>  
            <td>{{ invoice.phone }}</td>
            <td>{{ invoice.address }} ,{{ invoice.city }}</td>
            <td>{{ invoice.total_order }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
    
    </tbody>
</table>



{% endblock %}
```

```
def invoice(request):
  if request.user.is_authenticated:
    invoices = Invoice.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
    return render(request, 'invoices.html', {'invoices':invoices})
  else:
    messages.success(request, "You Must Be Logged In To View This Page !")
    return redirect('login')
```

Comment: Share the table and the generated model

Comment: added models.py and .html

Comment: @hammad khan yes, and based on that I didn't add id field, do you have any idea about how to solve this please ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is appearing because your database table `erp_app_invoice` is expecting a column named `id`, but it doesn't exist in your "models.py".
Generally, Django creates an `id` field automatically as an AutoField when you do not specify one explicitly.

Comment: yes, and based on that I didn't add id field, do you have any idea about how to solve this please ?

Answer (score 0):

thank you i have solved this issue by dropping the table from MySQL workbench and re-run dp.py again and migrate all data and it worked (you can drop the model table only if you don't want to loose other data)
Note: this action will erase all previous data

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).